# libxml2 is not able to parse external/internal entity from xml string in c++?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm parsing xml string using libxml2 SAX API's.

Following is xml string contains external entity:

```
string xmlString= "<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE copyright [ <!ELEMENT copyright (#PCDATA)> <!ENTITY c SYSTEM "http://www.xmlwriter.net/copyright.xml">]><copyright>&c;</copyright>"
```

also have xml string having internal entity:

```
string xmlString = "<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?><!DOCTYPE author [  <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>  <!ENTITY js "Jo Smith">]><author>&js;</author>"
```

I'm parsing these xml string using libxml2 SAX API's as follows:

```
  xmlSAXUserParseMemory(&xmlSAXHandler, NULL, xmlString.c_str(), xmlString.length);
```

But whiling parsing external/internal entity parser gives following error:

```
Entity 'c' not defined
```

any pointer to resolve this issue? so that I will get the value of external/internal entity parsed correctly?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this problem?